# how do I pass a variable from one script to another

Tags: javascript

Here is a script I can't get to work correctly.
It's purpose is to check whether a check box is checked and then to call a second
routine that responds, dependent on what the selectedindex (sindex) was shown to be when I originally called the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkB(ctrl,sindex) {  //get the state of the check box 
var sindex = {
    0: 0,
    1: 1,
    2: 2,
    3: 3
 };


if (ctrl.checked == true) { 
return function( which ) {
replaceContentmainobjectOn(sindex [which]);
} else {    
if (ctrl.checked == false) { 
replaceContentmainobjectOff();
}   
} 
}
</script>
```

here is the second script that is called

```
var replaceContentmainobjectOn =(function() {
var info = {
    0: 2,
    1: 1,
    2: 2,
    3: 3
 };

    return function( which ) {
    document.getElementById('ecwid-productoption-8840317-mainobject').selectedIndex = ( info[ which ] ) ;
};

}())
```

This is what I'm calling the first routine with

```
onclick="checkB(this,sindex);
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete working demonstration of your problem with a tool like http://jsfiddle.net?  Also why are you returning `function` objects?

Comment: The first script that you post doesn't look valid.

Comment: very wet behind the ears here.. 
I need to be able to supply the var info to the second routine when I call it from the first. How do you do that? Global Variables....???
It's very confusing being a noobie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two individual `<script>` blocks share the same execution scope, the global scope. All variables you create in the global scope inside one `<script>` are accessible in the other.

```
<script>
    var a = 5;
</script>

<script>
    alert( a );
</script>
```

Same applies to functions.

```
<script>
    var b = function( c ){ return c; }
</script>

<script>
    alert( b(12) );
</script>
```

That you can rule-out, your problem seems to lay in the first script, which is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Thanks .. that's what I was trying to figure out... 
Maybe I can develop a routine that will make use of this concept..